# A little problem with this Probability distribution $P\{X=n\}=\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}p$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In solving a probability exercise, they give me a random variable $X$ with a geometric distribution of parameter $p \; \;\;0<p<1$ such that probability function of $X$ is $P\{X=n\}=\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}p$ for $n\geq 1$.
And they use some property that I don't know and they get this:
$$ P\{X>n\}=\left(1-p\right)^{n}
$$
Could someone explain how they do it?

Comment: Sum $P(X=k)$ from $k=n+1$ to infinity. This is a geometric sum.

Comment: The probability that the first success happens after more than $n$ attempts is the probability there are no successes in $n$ attempts which is $(1-p)^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P}[X>n]=\sum_{x=n+1}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{x-1}=p(1-p)^n\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^y=p(1-p)^n\cdot \frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=(1-p)^n$$

Comment: Thank for the answer. I couldn´t understand that step.

Comment: @Luther : is it clear now? by the way did you forget to accept my answer?